# Local Variable Scope in Tornado (python)

Tags: python, html, templates, tornado

just wondering what the deal is with the scope of variables in a tornado template. I have this code in a template, but it fails!

```
    {% set dictionary = {'a' : 1, ... more letters here ... 'z' : 26} %}
    {% set sum = 0 %}
    {% for y in x %}
        {% sum += int(dictionary[y.lower()]) #x is a string, y a char %}
    {% end %}
    {{ sum }}
```

But I get:

```
ParseError: unknown operator: 'sum'
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 7):

Just use `set` before the `sum +=`

```
{% set dictionary = {'a' : 1, ... more letters here ... 'z' : 26} %}
{% set sum = 0 %}
{% for y in x %}
    {% set sum += int(dictionary[y.lower()]) #x is a string, y a char %}
{% end %}
{{ sum }}
```